# Wampserver 2.2 PHP version 5.4.3, Apache 2.4.2 and MySql 5.5.24

Tags: wampserver

I have been searching for Wampserver 2.2 (with PHP version 5.4.3, Apache 2.4.2 and MySQL 5.5.24) all day, I want this specific version because its the only one that runs on my computer without errors, please can someone direct me to a link where I can download it. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that mix actually exists but all versions of WAMPServer can be downloaded [from here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%202/)